# How do we formulate philosophical theories?

Tags: epistemology, knowledge

Various epistemological systems have their own way of arriving at knowledge. For example, the cornerstone of arriving at scientific knowledge is both induction and observation.

Then, what is the main way that philosophical knowledge is arrived at? Is it by use of reason? by logic? Is it formulated synthetic a priori? Does the philosophical field(metaphysics, ethics, etc.) matter?

Comment: Epistemology is a massive branch of philosophy. You really need to ask something more specific.

Comment: What is the fundamental way in which we reach philosophical truths(deduction, senses, reason)? I would have thought that the answer was quite specific.

Comment: Philosophy is not science or mathematics, for most philosophers it is not about "philosophical truths". Trying to understand it on the model of science, as you seem to attempt, is rather unpromising. It is more about generating ideas, reflecting on them, analyzing conceptions in other fields, including art and science, etc.

Comment: Scientific knowledge: induction (maybe...), observation (obviously), experiment, mathematics, imagination. Philosophical knowledge (if any): observation (obviously), reasoning (supported by logic and argumentation), imagination.

Comment: "philosophical 'truths'" What are they ? Some example ?

Comment: The method is abduction or 'inference to the best explanation'. We eliminate unworkable ideas by deriving formal contradictions. Or this is the theory, In practice the method is largely ignored for the sake of defending unworkable views.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Epistemology is the study of knowledge, so the question as it stands is what role does knowledge play in philosophy, often understood to be justfied, true belief (JTB). JTB is the means by which we separate reality from fiction. Illusion, delusion, confabulation, fallacy, and deception are experiences which cause us to have a false representation of the state of affairs. Philosophical knowledge-how and -that are generally arrived at through skepticism, rationalism, and empiricism, in contrast to indoctrination and divine revelation.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Just any philosophical theory. That is why I wrote 'truths' instead of truths.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me the problematic of this question lies in the phrase 'philosophical knowledge.' Philosophy isn't about creating *knowledge*. Philosophy aims to create *understanding*, and that is a different kettle of fish. If you want an analogy, you can think of the quest for *knowledge* as the use of a magnifying glass or microscope — something that allows us to examine other things in fine detail — and the quest for *understanding* as the act of shedding the light that makes such knowledge-tools useable.

We would not have modern empirical science, except that a whole lot of people who were inarguably philosophers worked through the basics of empiricism, so that we discovered how to look at things correctly. The modern pretense that 'Science' is a thing *sui generis* merely shows how effective philosophy was at outlining its core principles.

The difference between *good* philosophy and *bad* philosophy (and yes, there is plenty of the latter) has nothing to do with whether what-is-said is 'true,' or even whether it constitutes 'knowledge' in any meaningful sense of the term. In fact, the nature of 'knowledge' is one of the things that philosophy tries to shed light on. Good philosophy is *convincing* to those who approach it with a properly skeptical suspension of disbelief; good philosophy tells a tale about something in the world that people have a hard time rejecting. This is true of science as well — science, as I said, derives from philosophy — except that science restricts itself to materialism by restricting moments of conviction to acts of observation. One does philosophy the same way one helps a friend buy a car: by shedding light on the various aspects of the decision so that they can be weighed, one against another, until the decision comes clear. It's just that philosophy deals with deeper and more subtle value judgements than the mere pros and cons of a particular situation.

Comment: Good answer! From my perspective, science and humanities have a lot in common. One of the main goals is to tell stories about the world that are convincing and provide some sense of understanding and explanation. Precisely what constitutes convincing arguments differ between disciplines (for instance, measurement and prediction are required in science) as well as, of course, the domain of investigation, but this basic structure of telling a story supported by convincing arguments, and a willingsness to revise the story in light of new arguments, is the same in different academic disciplines.